# get subdomain in htaccess and route to a new folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

Is it possible to extract the subdomain part of a domain and use it like a variable in an .htaccess file?

Example

```
mysub.domain.com
```

What I'm looking for

```
(*).domain.com /$
```

after that the "mysub" is inside the "$-Sign"

Completely I want to route to another subfolder
normally mysub.domain.com routes to the "maindist" folder
now I want to do it more dynamically, so I want to route inside the folder which has the name of the subdomain

```
mysub.domain.com 
normal route->maindist 
after htaccess route->mysub
```

in best case I can do that without notice of the user, so without changing the addressbar from the browser.

Hope somebody can help and explain.

Comment: So you want `mysub.domain.com` to go to `domain.com/mysub`?